# No developer application on my page

Tags: facebook-page

I'm currently working on website for a local association for which I'm using Drupal CMS. There's a [facebook module](http://drupal.org/project/fb_social) for drupal that integrates all FB social plug-ins. Using it requires an Application ID. I've connected to FB page of the association, with the credentials they gave me but I've hit a wall because I can't access any of the FB Developers account features, hence I can't generate any app ID.

When I visit https://developers.facebook.com it simple redirects me to the association FB page and that's all there is to it. Googling around I read that their account should be "confirmed". I followed the procedure which involves giving out phone number etc, but still can't access anything related to devs.

I admit I'm completely lost and out of clues. Are there particular steps to follow for association/company FB pages?
Is there any particular downside if I use my personal FB account to get this famous APP ID?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Igy. I'll go through the linked article, fully read it and report back.

Comment: @Igy http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28449/facebook-business-accounts-for-managing-developing-applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've connected to FB page of the association, with the credentials they gave me

And what kind of credentials are these?

A developer has to be a natural person, which means a normal user account – not a page account or something like that.

Comment: That must be the issue. The FB account/page was created by someone within the association and what I'm using is the email/pass for the FB page. I'll go through the article Igy linked as it seems it explains the differences between business pages and normal accounts. Deciding in what case to use a normal account or a page should clear up the process. I'm fairly new to all the FB features integration on a website so still lots to learn about the ins and outs of it.